# What are the ways to send rich content to a web service from an android app?

Tags: android, rest

Suppose I want to build an app that will let users create profiles and share content, what are the alternatives to REST calls to a web services.

The user will potentially send images and videos and sound bites along with text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOAP to access web service. It's an XML based protocol.

W3Schools has [great page](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/default.asp) -of course- about Web Services tutorial